# flask static files in redhat openshift cloud

Tags: python, flask, openshift

I'm trying to deploy flask app to openshift express. The problem is that links to css files are not working. My application folder layout is as follows:

```
/wsgi
    /static
    /myapp
        /main
            /pages
            /static
```

Here "wsgi" and first "static" folders are provided by openshift. However, I put all static files inside main/static, and created flask app inside myapp/**_*init*_**.py file as follows:

```
app = Flask("myapp", template_folder='main/pages', static_folder='main/static')
```

Now, readme file inside static folder, provided by openshift says that in order to serve static files from different path, I have to use .htaccess file to rewrite url. But I couldn't get it right. Of course, the problem goes away if I copy all my static files to the first "static" folder provided by openshift. I just do not want that. So, can someone help me to serve my static files from my own static folder?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your .htaccess file? Also, try running a `rhc app tail -a appname` to see if there is anything in your log files. They might be able to tell you what directories your app is trying to serve content from.